# High charts not showing all the values on X-asix

Tags: php, highcharts

I am using high-chart to generate graph.

**Generated graph**:

[image]

The values passed to X-axis are:

```
["2510-24","2510-48","2510G-48","2520-24-PoE","2520-8-PoE","2520G-24-PoE","2520G-8-PoE","2530ya-24G","2530ya-24G-2SFPP","2530ya-24G-PoEP","2530ya-24G-PoEP-2SFPP","2530ya-48","2530ya-48-PoEP","2530ya-48G","2530ya-48G-2SFPP","2530ya-48G-PoEP","2530ya-48G-PoEP-2SFPP","2530ya-8G","2530ya-8G-PoEP","2530yb-24","2530yb-8","2530yb-8-PoEP","2610-24","2610-24-PWR","2610-48","2610-48-PWR","2615-8-PoE","2620-24","2620-24-PoEP","2620-24-PPoEP","2620-48" ...]
```

Why is the generated graph not displaying all the values instead of taking alternate values? How I can get all the values displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase height of the frame like,

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 2000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```